# Count number of each unique value in pandas column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
df['group'] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]
df['Sex'] = ['male', 'female','male', 'male','male', 'female','male', 'male','male', 'female','female', 'female',]

df

    group   Sex
1      1    male
2      1    female
3      1    male
4      1    male
5      1    male
6      1    female
7      2    male
8      2    male
9      2    male
10     2    female
11     2    female
12     2    female
```

Each group has 6 people in it. Some are male, some are female. I want to get a dataframe which counts for every group in `group` the number of males and the number of females.

**For example:**

- group 1 --> 4 male, 2 female
- group 2 --> 3 male, 3 female

The details on how the result is presented is not important to me.
I have tried to use groupby, but there is no function (count, sum, mean, nunique...) which tells me the ratio between male and female.

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```
pd.crosstab(df['group'], df['Sex'])
```

```
Sex    female  male
group              
1           2     4
2           3     3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Both solutions are very nice :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby()` method ,`value_counts()` method and `unstack()` method:

```
result=df.groupby('group')['Sex'].value_counts().unstack()
```

Now If you print `result` you will get:

```
Sex     female  male
group       
1       2       4
2       3       3
```